# What will happen if I pass Current through Permanent bar Magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

Following the Picture below,
If I Conduct current through Permanent magnet Bar and hold the battery still. Will the magnet move in any direction ? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I would think that based that it would alter the overall magnetic field slightly based on the direction the current was flowing through the magnet relative to the direction it was polarized in. Keep in mind a normal electromagnet at reasonable levels of current needs many many cols to produce a usable magnetic field. Unsure what you mean by "*will the magnet move in any direction*".

Answer (score 1):

If the material of the bar magnet is electrically conductive, then current will flow through the bar magnet.

According to Maxwell's Laws, that electric current will generate a magnetic field. The generated magnetic field may alter the magnetic polarization of the magnet.

However, the magnet will not move.